# windows smb connection, can't fix system error 53

Tags: smb, netbios

This issue tortures me days and still can't fix it: I have a file share server and I can access it from my windows client.

From the client, I am using net use command to connect the file share by using some specific user like:

net use y: \ia0.myserver.com\fs Password123! /user:corpuser2258@myserver.com

I have a script, which uses net use to connect to share by an user, do some file operations, then disconnect from share.

The script will loop on different users to do the above things. The problem is, script is doing well, until about 200 hundreds of loops, then net use will fail. The system error 53 has occurred.

At this point, my client cannot connect to the share anymore. I searched a lot on webs and tried various methods mentioned, like reboot netbios or other related services, but none of them can work.

The only way for now is reboot client, and then everything is back to normal.

Since the scrip works fine every time for the first hundreds of users, there should be no network or server issue. As long as I reboot client the system error 53 issue will gone. It looks like something in client should be rebooted or change to some initial state but I can't fingure out.

I hope someone could help to identify and fix the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give any other info like network capture (wireshark)